# Can not deserialize instance of model.* out of START_ARRAY token\n at

Tags: json, rest, spring-boot

I make traning REST service and now I try to add new item.

model Message:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="message")
public class Message{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "MESSAGE")
    private String message;
    @Column(name = "AUTHOR")
    private String author;
    @Column(name = "CREATED")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date created;

    public Message() {}

    public Message(Long id, String message, String author) {
        this.id = id;
        this.message = message;
        this.author = author;
        this.created = new Date();
    }
+ getters / setters
```

MessageController:

```
@RestController
public class MessageController {

    @Autowired
    private MessageRepository messageRepository;

    @RequestMapping(
        value = "/api/messages",
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> addMessage(@RequestBody Message newMessage) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(messageRepository.save(newMessage), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

Error:

> 2016-11-06 10:52:53.857 WARN 1100 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
>   .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to read HTTP
>   message:
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of
>   com.sttech.springrest.model.Message out of START_ARRAY token at
>   [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@6ccdce8a; line: 1, column: 1];
>   nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not
>   deserialize instance of com.sttech.springrest.model.Message out of
>   START_ARRAY token at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@6ccdce8a;
>   line: 1, column: 1]

Through Postman I send new data in json and get Postman answer

```
[
  {
    "message": "Hello World1",
    "author": "ABC"
  }
]
```

> "exception":
>   "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
>   "message": "Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of
>   com.sttech.springrest.model.Message out of START_ARRAY token\n at
>   [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@6ccdce8a; line: 1, column: 1];
>   nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not
>   deserialize instance of com.sttech.springrest.model.Message out of
>   START_ARRAY token\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@6ccdce8a;
>   line: 1, column: 1]"

How to fix it? I think the model does't get id.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your service expects a single message. However, you send an array of messages (though it only contains a single message).

So instead of:

```
[
  {
    "message": "Hello World1",
    "author": "ABC"
  }
]
```

you should just send:

```
{
  "message": "Hello World1",
  "author": "ABC"
}
```

Comment: How I can send an array?

Comment: You mean: how can I handle a JSON array? You need to change the signature of the API to `public ResponseEntity<?> addMessage(@RequestBody List<Message> newMessages)` and then process a list of messages.